# how to change the value with the another array value if it matched with the another array value

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Hii here is my simple logical question

**this is my reference array**

```
referenceArray =[{name : "animal" , source :['duck', 'cat'], target:['water', 'ground']},
                 {name : "car" , source :['tata', 'kia'], target:['tiago', 'sector']},
                 {name : "bike" , source :['honda', 'hero'], target:['livo', 'xtream']}
                    ]
```

this is i want to modify the source and target array with the above `referenceArray` array

```
 originalArray =[{source : 'water' , target : 'hero'},
                 {source : 'tata' , target : 'ground'},
                 {source : 'livo' , target : 'kia'},
                ]
```

**but i want the final output like this**

```
originalArray =[{source : 'animal' , target : 'bike'},
                {source : 'car' , target : 'animal'},
                {source : 'bike' , target : 'car'},
               ]
```

**can anyone help me out please that is soo appreciatable**

Comment: What have you tried to achieve this?

Comment: initially i have lot duplicated objects with some name like `animal` like so reduced the size of objected with array.reducers and putted what common elements with the same name so i got like that

Comment: Shouldn't the target props of the elements of originalArray have values that are found in the target props of referenceArray?  For example target: hero - hero is only in source, not target, of reference array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply build a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) of the reference array with each `source` and `target` elements keyed against the `name`, then map over the `originalArray` accessing the `Map`. Keep in mind this does nothing to avoid possible overlap of source and target arrays.

```js
const referenceArray = [{ name: "animal", source: ['duck', 'cat'], target: ['water', 'ground'] }, { name: "car", source: ['tata', 'kia'], target: ['tiago', 'sector'] }, { name: "bike", source: ['honda', 'hero'], target: ['livo', 'xtream'] }];
const originalArray = [{ source: 'water', target: 'hero' }, { source: 'tata', target: 'ground' }, { source: 'livo', target: 'kia' },]

const referenceMap = new Map()
for (const { name, source, target } of referenceArray) {
  for (const k of [...source, ...target]) {
    referenceMap.set(k, name);
  }
}

const result = originalArray.map(({ source, target }) => (
  {
    source: referenceMap.get(source),
    target: referenceMap.get(target)
  }
));

console.log(result)
```